# Linked & Related sidebar items would look better vertically centered

Tags: feature-request, design

I don't know where suggest this, so I posted here a question.

Just one line of CSS can improve vertical alignment of items in the sidebar for "Linked" and "Related"...

| Actual | Suggested |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

###### original selector:

```css
.show-votes .sidebar-linked .spacer, .show-votes .sidebar-related .spacer {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    display: flex;
}
```

###### suggested:

```css
.show-votes .sidebar-linked .spacer, .show-votes .sidebar-related .spacer {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: Why is that necessarily an improvement?

Comment: simply a design suggestion, 
when the item has long title it goes 2 or 3 lines, at that moment the alignment with the left badge is not right anymore
(I think is not intended) - of course could be aligned with the first line instead

Comment: I've put the screenshots side by side, so it's a bit easier to see the difference. The difference isn't all that noticeable to people who don't know what you're actually changing. This question would be substantially improved by A) a more detailed description of what you find to be wrong; and B) editing the screen shots to 1) use the same exact dimensions, showing *exactly* the same portion of the screen, 2) include at least a couple freehand red circles to explicitly indicate what it is that you're saying is a problem/improvement, and 3) have smaller left/right margins (but not none).

Comment: Frankly, the suggested version _does_ look better, if for no other reason than it gets the the score box to not be _above_ the start of the text in multi-line question titles (which is most of them).

Comment: I expect the baseline of the score to be aligned with the baseline of the first line of text, just like a bullet in a bulleted list. That's not how it is currently either, but I don't think the center-aligned version looks better, just different.

Comment: Please explain the difference of effect & why you think that is an improvement. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: In the example screenshot it looks slightly better because the score box no longer pokes out above the text since they're mostly two lines, but it'd be best if the box would align to the top of the text instead so it is more consistent independent of the number of lines of text there are.

Comment: Now that you've pointed this out I can't unsee it and it's driving me crazy. Thanks.

Comment: it would look better if they both started from the same top line, not centered